# Getting an error while sending the "sendkeys" in appium server

Tags: java, automation, appium, sendkeys

In appium server , am trying to send the keys inside the text box , where am facing this trouble

Call to 'sendKeys' failed
[element.sendKeys("hello")] Error response status: 12, InvalidElementState - An element command could not be completed because the element is in an invalid state (e.g. attempting to click a disabled element). Selenium error: Cannot set the element to 'hello'. Did you interact with the correct element?

can someone help me on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you share more info . Code snippet would be helpful in your case. And in which platform are you trying this?

INFO : InvalidElementState comes in where when elements either of race condition of appium interaction with elements.

```
Selenium error: Cannot set the element to 'hello'. Did you interact with the correct element?
```

This appears when find element value of xpath/id is not correct as well .

Answer (score 0):

1-Try following may help you in debugging:

```
driver.pressKey(KeyEvent(AndroidKey.A))
```

2-Use wait till the element to be clickable or make sure for your element locator

```
elementToBeClickable()
```